# Setting for tokens values to variables

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I was just wondering how you would set the token values from a for statement into variables in a batch script then perform whatever actions your script requires.

Myconfigfile.config has below lines:

```
 C:\logs|logfolder1|*.log|30
 C:\logs|logfolder12|*.log|30
```

So I have this line:

```
for /F "delims=| tokens=*" %%A in (Myconfigfile.config) do echo %%A
```

I what

```
 location="tokens=1"
 subfolder="tokens=2"
 pattern="tokens=3"
 range="tokens=4"
```

Then

```
 echo the location is  %location%
 echo the subfolder is  %subfolder%
 echo the pattern is  %pattern%
 echo the range is  %range%
```

Obviously I could do that with 4 for statements but I suspect there is a better more effcient way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    for /F "delims=| tokens=1-4" %%A in (Myconfigfile.config) do (
     set "location=%%A"
     set "subfolder=%%B"
     set "pattern=%%C"
     set "range=%%D"

      echo the location is  !location!
      echo the subfolder is  !subfolder!
      echo the pattern is  !pattern!
      echo the range is  !range! 
    )
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the *names* of each one of the desired tokens:
rem (this is the only line that require changes)
set namesOfTokens=location subfolder pattern range


rem Assemble the correct "tokens=..." and set commands
set "tokens= ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
set "setCommands="
set i=0
for %%a in (%namesOfTokens%) do (
   set /A i+=1
   for %%i in (!i!) do set setCommands=!setCommands! set "%%a=%%%%!tokens:~%%i,1!" ^&
)

rem DO IT!
for /F "delims=| tokens=1-%i%" %%A in (Myconfigfile.config) do %setCommands:~0,-1%

echo the location is  %location%
echo the subfolder is  %subfolder%
echo the pattern is  %pattern%
echo the range is  %range%
```

It is **very important** that last character in the long for command be the "&" character. Please, report the result...

Comment: Excuse me. My answer is _entirely different_ than npocmaka's one. My method allows to insert/reorder/delete any number of tokens modifying just one line. You could obtained the other information by just entering: `for /?` (that I incorrectly assumed you already know...)